# How can fix the error in Android Studio? AOSP image error 0x500

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I have created successfully a virtual device to test system images of smartphones. In the Android Studio, I get an error message in the event log.

```
16:51 PM Emulator: /mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/qemu/android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBindBuffer:433 error 0x500
```

I have tried to change graphic settings without success. Have anyone advice how to fix this issue?

[image]

Kind regards
Georg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create/Edit the  emulator with following properties

```
Emulated Performance ==> Graphics ==> "Software - GLES 2.0"
```

Comment: Thanks to Swayangjit,

this was the right hint!
Best Regards Georg

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still at the moment I can't. The rules of the website didn't accept my upvote. :)