# AOSP image error 0x500 switch to automatic

Tags: android-source

Referenced to my question before.

How I can fix this issue? Is it possible after the fix, to switch the settings to automatic(Emulated Performance ==> Graphics ==> automatic)?

I add drivers into the device folder in the repository and run the bash script, but without success. Can you give me a hint to fix it?

Kind regard
Georg

[How can fix the error in Android Studio? AOSP image error 0x500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58361384/how-can-fix-the-error-in-android-studio-aosp-image-error-0x500/58362772#58362772)

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the graphics?

Switch to software mode from automatic or hardware, and render everything in software.

There is a couple of more options to run in different modes more specifically (with Linux or MacOS):

- `auto` (automatic)
- `host` (hardware)
- `swiftshader_indirect` (Quick Boot-compatible variant of SwiftShader to render graphics using software acceleration)
- `guest` (side software rendering, also it's the lowest graphics quality and performance)

Usage:

```
emulator -avd [your_emulator_avd] -gpu [one_of_the_modes_above]
```

or edit the config.ini file with parameters:

```
hw.gpu.enabled = [false|true]
hw.gpu.mode = [mode]
```

or edit the hadware-qemu.ini on Linux for qemu. I imagine it is the same on MacOS and Windows, just edit the file config.ini for your given emulator.

If nothing works try some of the older deprecated modes like:

- swiftshader: deprecated in version 27.0.2
- mesa: deprecated in version 25.3

For Windows there are additional mods (had to look it up):

- `angle_indirect` (Windows only mode) Quick Boot-compatible variant of ANGLE Direct3D to render graphics using software acceleration. This uses DirectX on Windows instead of OpenGL, requires Windows 10, Windows 8.1, or Windows 7 SP1.
- older version is `angle` and it was deprecated in version 27.0.2

Also try rendering with [Skia](https://skia.org) through adb shell set this system property:

```
su
setprop debug.hwui.renderer skiagl
stop
start
```

When using images for API level 27 or higher, the emulator can render the Android UI with [Skia](https://skia.org).

Comment: I found the config.ini file in the specific test folder from this device.( \.android\avd\mySecondTest.avd) . When I set the settings, after a start of the emulator all the changes setting automaticaly back to default.(hw.gpu.enabled=no and hw.gpu.mode=off). 
What does it mean? Does the emulator miss specific driver for this virtual device?

Comment: @Georgbor you cannot just set the gpu to off, you must set the mode, software mode in your case. Just do this, set the mode like so, hw.gpu.mode = swiftshader_indirect, and leave the gpu on, set it to true, it will use the integrated gpu anyway. If you see no change after these values, check the specification modes for your version.

Comment: In the meantime I figure out, this setting make sense just in case of a pysical device. When I use this AOSP image in a emulator(Android-Studio), I can switch this setting to software(Emulated Performance ==> Graphics ==> automatic). This image works in a good performence in the emulator.